# Volume of objects like hypercube / hypersphere : $V_{n}^{(m)}(r) = \dots$

Tags: geometry, volume, solid-geometry, dimensional-analysis, platonic-solids

I am looking for some general form of equation for calculating volume for specific geometry objects.

---

The main idea is to find :

$$
V_{n}^{(m)}(r) = \dots
$$
Where:
$V$ - volume of object
$n$ - regular polygon
$m$ - dimension
$r$ - radius of described sphere

---

It's easy to find equation for hypersphere, it is :
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} V_{n}^{(m)}(r) = \pi^{\frac{m}{2}} \frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2} + 1)} * r^m
$$
For $m=2$, general equation is :
$$
V_{n}^{(2)}(r) = \frac{1}{2} n \sin(\frac{2 \pi}{n}) * r^2
$$

Thanks to Platonic solids there is equation for $m=3$ and $n=3$, $n=5$ :
$$
V_{3}^{(3)}(r) = \frac{8 \sqrt{3}}{27} * r^3
$$
$$
V_{5}^{(3)}(r) = \frac{2 \sqrt{3} (5 + \sqrt{5})}{9} * r^3
$$

---

In general it's easy to see that equation will have form :
$$
V_{n}^{(m)}(r) = f(n, m) * r^m
$$

---

Is it possible to find exact equation ?

What worries me is limit in count of Platonic solids for $\text{3D}$ dimension case ($m=3$).
I wasn't also able to find any equation for other hyperobjects.

Comment: There are three regular 3D polyhedra with triangular faces (tetrahedron, octahedron, icosahedron), they can be distinguished by the number of faces around each vertex (3, 4, 5 respectively). This is written using https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol

Comment: I don't really understand your definition of $V_n^{(m)}$. What polytope is this referring to? For example, what polytope is $V_3^{(5)}$ referring to (in my understanding, there could be two). What polytope is $V_5^{(5)}$ referring to (I can't think of a single).

Answer (score 1):

Tables I.i, I.ii, and I.iii, pp.292-295 of Regular Polytopes by H.S.M. Coxeter (3rd edition, Dover, ISBN-13 978-0-486-61480-9, ISBN-10 0-486-61480-8) have a column for the content (the name for $n$D equivalent of volume) of Platonic solids in 3D, their equivalents in 4D, and the 3 kinds in dimensions 5 and above.  This is given in terms of the side length $2l$, another column gives the radii ${}_jR$ of the $j$D subpolytopes.  There are 28 rows total, so forgive me for not typing them all up.

#### Table I.iii: The three regular polytopes in $n$ dimensions ($n \ge 5$)

| Name | ${}_j R/l$ | $C/(2l)^n$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Regular Simplex | $\left(\frac{2}{j+1}-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ | $\frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ |
| Cross Polytope | $\left(\frac{2}{j+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ | $\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}n}}{n!}$ |
| Measure Polytope | $\left(n-j\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ | $1$ |